# How to get acces to XML tag attributes via XPath parser settings?

Tags: feeds

I need to parse XML attributes via Feeds Importer **XPath parser**[image: my paarser settings]

exitsting XML tag structure is:

```
<MunicipalUnion Id="2a1c7bdb-05ea-492f-9e1c-b3999f79dcbc" Name="Moscow" TypeMU="city"/>
```

If i write **@Id, @Name, @TypeMU**, result is:
[image]

Comment: Not sure if it will work, but maybe you should try `/RaionResponse/MunicipalUnions` as your context and `/MunicipalUnion/@Id`, `/MunicipalUnion/@Name`, `/MunicipalUnion/@TypeMU` as your queries

Comment: no this doesn't work

Comment: Вы смогли настроить импорт? как должны выглядеть правильно заполненные поля?

Answer (score 1):

Solution is:
using [Xpath string() function](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp#string)

string(@Id)

string(@Name)

string(@TypeMU)

[image]